# Se célula alterada, deslocar valor antigo pro lado

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou começando a usar o VBA com o pacote office, como ainda conheço pouco estou tendo dificuldades para pegar esta funcionalidade.

Estava tentando fazer algo simples e precisava de ajuda para entender como funciona:

Preciso que se uma célula na coluna I for alterada, o conteúdo antigo dela seja copiada para outra imediatamente a coluna H, sem ter que clicar em nenhum botão, ex:

Tenho a seguinte situação:

H13: Texto 01

I13: Texto 02

Após inserir o valor - Texto 03 - na I13, Teriamos como resultado

H13: Texto 02

I13: Texto 03

Sei que consigo fazer isso com VBA, mas preciso da sintaxe do VBA para começar a fazer algo mais avançado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava usando o seguinte código.. mas ele estava copiando o valor atual, queria que ele copiasse o ultimo valor existente... alem disso queria que ela so funcionasse se a coluna H não estiver vazia...

Answer (score 0):

Option Explicit

```
Private Const H As Long = 8
```

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
On Error GoTo CleanExit

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim Coluna As Long

Dim linha As Long

Coluna = Target.Column

If Coluna = 9 Then

    linha = Target.Row

    Cells(linha, 8) = Cells(linha, Coluna)

End If
```

CleanExit:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True

On Error GoTo 0
```

End Sub